# Where can I ask a question about an obscure/dialect programming language?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm starting to use multiple programming languages and sometimes the syntax for things trips me up. I would like to be able to Google "How to write a for loop in Optoscript" and have a relevant answer show up in Google just like every other major language, but this does not always work. I thought that Stack Exchange would be a good place to ask that kind of question (and post the answer from the manual that takes forever to load) but figured I'd ask on Meta first. Should I post these questions? To what stack should I post them?

Comment: (the manual is here: http://www.opto22.com/documents/1700_PAC_Control_Users_Guide.pdf)

Comment: This question could be generalized to include all PLC programming language questions.

Comment: Sorry @T-Rez I feel your post is a bit unclear, would you mind fixing that? What is it you want to ask, so we can suggest sites to do so?

Comment: If you want to write a question about programing languages then the best place would be [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) please correct me if your question is different and I will edit my comment to provide the best help